# dependencies and devDependencies when using webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, package

Does it make sense to put any modules into `package.json` `dependencies` when I use webpack?

When I want to develope a package, I use `git clone <url>` then `npm install`, then npm installs all `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from `package.json` file and it makes sense.

When I'm end-user and I just want to install some package into my `node_modules` to use it in my project, I run `npm install package-name`, then npm installs `package-name` with **only** its `dependencies`, and it makes sense too.

But does it make sense to put any modules into `dependencies` when I use `webpack`? The webpack will bundle all dependencies into eg. `bundle.js`, so, for me, there is no need to install dependencies then (while they're included into `bundle.js` file).

Let's assume that I put all neccessary modules into `devDependencies` (keep the `dependencies` object empty) for my project: `my-project`, bundle it with webpack and publish:

- the developer-user will use `git clone <url to my_project>`, then run `npm install`, then npm will install `devDependencies` from `package.json` (and ommit empty `dependencies` object), then it is ready to develope.
- the end-user will use `npm install my-project`, then npm will install `my-project`, do not install `devDependencies` *(because this is for production)* and do not install `dependencies` *(because `dependencies` object in `package.json` remain empty)*. Putting anything into `dependencies` **would double** the dependencies: both the dependencies would be installed, and the same dependencies would be accessible in the `bundle.js` file.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there *may* be no dependencies once it's been transpiled with webpack. However, some packages are multi-purpose and may be used in multiple ways, so in some circumstances dependencies may still be required.

If you look at the `package.json` [specification](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), there are two possible entry points, 'main' and 'browser'. There is also the proposed '[module](https://github.com/dherman/defense-of-dot-js/blob/master/proposal.md)' entry point. It is currently under [discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4674) about how to handle these in webpack and users seem to want webpack to prioritize them as `module > browser > main`, however `browser` is currently used by webpack first.

The idea behind prioritizing them in the order `module > browser > main` is presumably that browsers could use the pre-transpiled stuff directly in "browser", whereas another project calling `require()` or `include()` on your package would use non-transpiled code from the "module" entry. The "module" entry code could contain modern JavaScript with new features and the project/package requiring it could then transpile it to their own specifications, using "[browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)" for example.

I found this question because I was wondering the same thing...